# Acrobat javascript API in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, adobe-reader

Is there any way to use Adobe Acrobat Javascript APIS in iOS platform for usage within iPhone and iPad apps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Reader X (newest) does not support iOS devices, only Android devices. So no, you cant use the acrobat javascript API in iOS. You would have to find some other pdf API, maybe the iphone has something bundled with it?

Comment: I couldnt find any api pdf scripting in iOS. I was wondering if i'm wrong or there is another solution.

Comment: ask another question, redefine the question or accept the answer i gave. I wont answer this question with a solution for something else than adobe-reader, as it is irrelevant to the tag and question.